# How to do pagination by using Codeigniter for data from multiple tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have read the tutorial of this topic. However, I want to do something more complicated. Here is the code from the example:

```
function Index(){

$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->load->library('table');

$config['base_url'] = "http://";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('data')->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 10;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['records'] = $this->db->get('data',$config['per_page'],$this->url->segment(3));

$this->load->view('new_view', $data);

}
```

I understand these codes, but I don't want to show the entire table. Instead of doing something like this `$data['records'] = $this->db->get('data',$config['per_page'],$this->url->segment(3));`, I want to show a result that is generated from multiple tables. And I have already got this information from pervious steps and stored in a variable, let's say `$final_result`.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can use the `$final_result` to do the pagination. I don't want to do a `get_where()`, since there will be too many conditions.